# Redirect to another domain after Python-social-auth login

Tags: python, django, redirect, python-social-auth

Is it possible redirect to another web after login with `python-social-auth`?

let's say:

```
<a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'facebook' %}?next={{ request.path }}"></a>
```

The example above is according to the documentation and it is working well, but when I try this:

```
<a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'facebook' %}?next=http://www.google.com/"></a>
```

I get the following error:

```
http://example.com:8000/accounts/profile/ Not Found
```

This makes sense; I don't have this URL defined

At this point I have been already logged in, but I see an error page.

But with the same configuration, if I redirect to my own site, this works, I think this is something about settings, but I don't know which one.

EDIT:

If I remove the `next` GET param in the first configuration, it raise the same error.

Comment: Did you try set the `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` variable in your settings?

Comment: @arcegk Yes, same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't safe to redirect to a different domain, e.g. `https://www.google.com`. To understand why, imagine that I send your users a link to:

```
http://www.yoursite.com/login?next=http://myevilsite.com
```

If your login page trusted the `next` url, then your users will be redirected to my site after they have logged in. I could use this for phishing attacks.

To prevent against this, Django checks that the next url is safe to redirect to. If it is not safe, then it will redirect to the `settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`, which defaults to `/accounts/profile/`. You can [see the code here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/c92123cc1dceeb800b3b8900e2e530ed19d78863/django/utils/http.py).

Comment: I understand this, nice to know where does `accounts/profile` comes from, I didn't found that in docs. Is there any way to catch the redirect and avoid it? or response just a JSON instead of a template? - This is not a full API but I wonder if it's possible. Thanks

Comment: The docs for the [django login view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.login) do say that the user will be redirected to `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`, which defaults to `/accounts/profile/`. If you want to avoid the 404 error, then either change the settings to a url that does exist, or add a view and a url pattern for that `/accounts/profile/`. That url/view could return html, json, or anything else you want. Unless you are logging in with an ajax request, it wouldn't be a good idea to return json.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I think there is some situations where it is interesting to redirect to another domain (ie: you have your backend under a different domain than your frontend).

After some investigation I found that you can control which domains are safe to redirect to (https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-core/blob/1d809941ab8a99af9e1bdf12bae548202c94eaa2/social_core/actions.py#L20).

Just add this to your `settings.py`:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_ALLOWED_REDIRECT_HOSTS = ['domain1', 'domain2']
```